# change the column direction in wpf datagrid

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, wpfdatagrid

I'm searching about WPF property that makes the columns direction to the right direction. 
In Windows Forms there is property named RightToLeft that makes this job, but i don't find any thing in WPF that do this job. Can any one help me, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about [FlowDirection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.flowdirection.aspx) property?

`<DataGrid FlowDirection="RightToLeft">`